# Copying a lotus notus database view and paste into word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, lotus-notes

The code below reads and inserts the email from lotus notes to an excel sheet. However I would like to read a lotus notes database and copy its content and paste it as a rich text into a word document.

I assume this line of code needs to be modified.

```
Set nitem = .GetFirstItem("Body")
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

```
Public Sub Lotus_Notes_Current_Email4()

Dim NSession As Object 'NotesSession
Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object 'NotesUIWorkspace
Dim NUIdoc As Object 'NotesUIDocument
Dim nitem As Object 'NotesItem
Dim lines As Variant

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.CurrentDocument
If Not NUIdoc Is Nothing Then
    With NUIdoc.Document
        Set nitem = .GetFirstItem("Body")
        If Not nitem Is Nothing Then
            lines = Split(nitem.Text, vbCrLf)
            Sheets(1).Activate
            Range("H8").Resize(UBound(lines) + 1, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(lines)
        End If
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Lotus Notes is not displaying an email"
End If

Set NUIdoc = Nothing
Set NUIWorkSpace = Nothing
Set NSession = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. Your entire script needs to be rewritten.

If you want to copy the contents of a view, then you need to start by opening a [NotesView](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESVIEW_CLASS.html) object.  Your current code is opening a NotesDocument object. To get the NotesView, you might want to use the [CurrentView](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CURRENTVIEW_PROPERTY_1026_ABOUT.html) property NotesUIWorkspace to get a NotesUIView object, and then use that objects [View](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ca/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_VIEW_PROPERTY.html) property.

Once you have the NotesView object, then I'm guessing you might want to want to use the [columns](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COLUMNS_PROPERTY.html) property to get at the data, but there are other ways you could go about it. Pretty much no matter what you do, though, you're going to have to handle the formatting of the data on your own.